# I can display all items in my MongoDB collection, but can't save to it: "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, express, mongoose

I am relatively new to Node.js, currently, I'm trying to make a Q&A app, the following functionalities are relevant to my question and what I have to make.

- List all discussions from MongoDB (this works).
- Add a discussion with properties: author, title, body through a form to Mongodb.
- Upon creating the new discussion, be redirected to a detail page of the newly made discussion.

This is my MongoDB structure: mongodb://localhost/Diskussrdb

The name of the collection is "discussions".

Currently, I am able to view all of my database records on localhost:3000/discussions

The page with the form for creating a new discussion is located at localhost:3000/discussions/create

*FIXED: However, pressing the submit button on the /create page doesn't do anything. I've been staring myself blind at tutorials online but I can't find anything that helps me out.*

*FIXED: New question: The submit now works, but returns a 404 on the adress "localhost:3000/submit". I added a console.log to the /submit router.post but it doesn't display in my prompt.*

**The submit works, and goes to LH:3000/discussions/submit, but it seems my app cannot find my collection. However, LH:3000/discussions lists all items currently in my MongoDB (Diskussr, collection: discussions), so it has to be linked correctly, somehow.**

**A console.log of the collection also returns "undefined".
This is the error: "Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined**
**

These are my code files:

discussions.js -- /routes

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Discussion = require('../models/discussions');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){

    // alle db records uitlussen, op render alldiscussions
    var db = req.db;
    Discussion.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('all_discussions', {
            "all_discussions" : docs
        });
        console.log(docs);
    });
});

router.get('/create', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('add_discussion', {title: 'Diskussr'});

});

router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {

    //set DB
    var db = req.db;

    //form vals
    var author = req.body.name;
    var title = req.body.title;
    var body = req.body.body;

    //set collection
    var collection = db.get('discussions');

    //insert
    collection.insert({
        "author" : author,
        "title" : title,
        "body" : body
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("Database submit error");
        }
        else {
            res.location("all_discussions");
            res.redirect("all_discussions");
        }
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

add_discussion.jade -- /views

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Start a discussion
  p Start a discussion here on #{title} and help eachother out.
  p Voeg hier uw vraag in:
  form(action="/submit" method="post" name="submit_discussion")
  input(id="name", placeholder="Your name" name="name")
  br
  br
  input(id="title", placeholder="Brief summary of your problem." name="title")
  br
  br
  input(id="body", placeholder="Explain your problem." name="body")
  br
  br
  button(type="sumbit" id="submit" value="submit") Submit
  br
```

discussions.js -- /models

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//schema discussions
var DiscussionSchema = new Schema({
    author: String,
    title: String,
    body: String,
    category: String,
    created: Date
},
{ collection : 'discussions' });

// model
var Discussion = mongoose.model('Discussion', DiscussionSchema, 'discussions');

// test functie: aanmaken vraag on load
// var firstDiscussion = new Discussion({author: "Testuser 1", title: "Testvraag via models"});
// console.log(firstDiscussion);

// //vraag saven
//  firstDiscussion.save(function (err, firstDiscussion){
//      if (err) return console.error(err);
//  });





module.exports = Discussion;
```

My lecturer told me to post this to StackOverflow, since he is not willing to help me out himself.

Comment: what happens when you put a break point in router.post('/submit', function(req, res) { ... } ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade is whitespace sensitive, if you want html elements to be contained within another, say a form tag, you need to indent them.

```
block content
  h1 Start a discussion
  p Start a discussion here on #{title} and help eachother out.
  p Voeg hier uw vraag in:
  
  form(action="/submit" method="post" name="submit_discussion")
      input(id="name", placeholder="Your name" name="name")
      br
      br
      input(id="title", placeholder="Brief summary of your problem." name="title")
      br
      br
      input(id="body", placeholder="Explain your problem." name="body")
      br
      br
      button(type="sumbit" id="submit" value="submit") Submit
      br
```

I would recommend using a debugger. To immediately see what is happening you can add a console output to the `router.post` to check that it is actually being called, like so:

```
router.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    console.log("POST received");
    // etc
}
```

**Further debugging:**

Add this app.use() code anywhere in your app.js above your router.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Received: " + req.method + " at " + req.originalUrl);
    next();
});
```

It'll get called everytime your app received a request, and then next(); moves on to your router. So you'll see:

> Received: GET at /create
>
> Received: POST at /submit

**Database Issue**

The issue with your database query is that you need to call insert on Discussion, not db.collection.get('Discussion');

Try:

```
Discussion.insert({
    "author" : author,
    "title" : title,
    "body" : body
}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        res.send("Database submit error");
    }
    else {
        res.location("all_discussions");
        res.redirect("all_discussions");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have suggestions as to where I could find a good debugger for Jade?

Comment: There are lots of resources for debugging NodeJS. If you're working on windows, you can get Visual Studio Community edition, and download NodeJS Tools, all free. You can also get a lighter Visual Studio Code, Microsoft have just released to debug NodeJS, which is available for OS X, Windows and Linux. You can also do development online through Cloud9, which has a debugger, and you only need a web browser, which is also free for one project.

Comment: Your indenting solution did the trick, the submit now does something but the POST doesn't seem to work, I don't get the console.log and no data is saved to the database.

Comment: Do you go to the expected address after pressing submit? See my updated answer for more debugging.

Comment: Good news, I can now press the submit button and it'll forward from localhost:3000/discussions/create to LH:3000/discussions/submit, however, I'm getting errors with my collections. I'll put them here and I'll update the question.

Error: "Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined"

Comment: Great news. I've updated my answer with advice on the database issue

Comment: Also please accept my answer if you have solved your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, Ryan. You've been of great help. I ultimately solved the issue by using the .save() method like so:

new Discussion({
  "author" : author,
  "title" : title,
  "body" : body
 }).save(function (err, doc) {